# Wordpress Conditional Radio Button Not Working

Tags: wordpress

Currently i am trying to convert HTML into WordPress plugin, i am trying the code given below.
the radio button selected has value style1, but the statement in else is being executed.

```
$style=get_option("Style"); 
if($style == "style1") 
{//code1
} else{
//code2
    }
```

P.S. - I am an amateur in wordpress programming.

Comment: I'm confused...can you show your html? Also, what's the desired end result?

Comment: just why else is being executed when value of $style is style1

Comment: If `$style` is actually `== 'style1'`, it's impossible for the `else` statement to be executed.

Comment: here's the whole code. http://txs.io/DZsb

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do [client-side scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting) using a [server-side scripting language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) (PHP).

Unless you decide to deal with [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) data from the server, you'll need to use JavaScript (or another client-side language) to achieve what you're trying to do.